# compare two table result on based of count of column of second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using mysql database.
I have two table one is `user_songs` and second is `user_like`

Fields of `user_song`:

```
id(auto incement)
song_id
user_id
song_name
song_file
```

Fields of `user_like`:

```
id(auto incement)
song_id
uder_id
like
```

In `user_like`  I am saving data where any user going like song so each row contain data like:

```
1 1 1 1
```

Please note like saves either 0 or 1.0 for dislike and 1 for like.

Now I need to find out top 20 most like songs `id` from `user_like` and get all data from `user_songs` from `user_songs`.

How to do this?
Thanks in advance to spend your valuable time to solve this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.totalLike
FROM    user_song a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  song_id, COUNT(*) totalLike
            FROM    user_like
            GROUP   song_id
        ) b ON a.song_id = b.song_ID
ORDER BY totalLike DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Caution: the query above doesn't handle tie up values on `totaluserLike` result. It will only display 20 records on the result list.

Comment: Hi ,Really nice.Inline view perfect suits here .Thanks for answer.My English is week so can you please explain what do you mean by "the query above doesn't handle tie up values on totaluserLike result".Please explain.Thanks for valuable time.

Comment: $rs=mysql_query("SELECT  a.*
    FROM    atr_songs a
        INNER JOIN
        (
   SELECT  song_id  ,count(*) totallike
            FROM    atr_like
    where 'like'=1
            GROUP  by song_id
        ) b ON a.song_id = b.song_ID
ORDER BY totalLike DESC
LIMIT 20 ") or 
die(mysql_error());

    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) 
    {
    $arr[] = $obj;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
    ?>

Comment: @mayurbhagat in you condition, `where 'like'=1` what is `LIKE` a column or an `ALIAS` of a column? and `LIKE` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @ jW I make it 'like' as per your comment of my second question..like is column name of table atr_like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395167/getting-syntax-error-in-mysql-php-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax

Comment: use backtick not single quote. `:)`

Comment: How stupid I am!really thank you so much I could not solve my both problem without your help.Actually I used back tick first time today in last 10 year.. :)